# Problems with 2 span elements inside <a> element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a text as a link, but I fails with 2 things:
 1. There is a blank space between the 2 span elements but I failed to remove it (`margin-right` and `margin-left` did nothing):
[image]

2. As I hover on the `rapitec` span element, I get a pointer cursor, whereas I get default cursor as I hover the  `.com` span element.

HTML:

```html
<a href="index.html">
  <span style="margin-right: 0; border: solid;" id="logoText">rapitec</span>
  <span style="margin-left: 0; border: solid;" id="logoPrefix">.com</span>
</a>
```

Comment: 1) https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: 2) Your example here does not reproduce what you are saying is happening, so provide a proper [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

A `<span>` is an inline element, and any whitespace *including linebreaks* between inline elements is shown as a single space.

You can remove the linebreak to make it work as desired:

```html
<a href="index.html">
  <span style="margin-right: 0; border: solid;" id="logoText">rapitec</span><span style="margin-left: 0; border: solid;" id="logoPrefix">.com</span>
</a>
```

Another option can be to use CSS `float:left` for the span-elements, but that may cause other unwanted effects for your layout if you don't do it carefully.

And about your 2) mouse pointer issue: I can't reproduce it here, and I don't see anything in what you posted that could cause it.

Comment: I think you just beat me to it! `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

Ways to fix the white-space-issue:

1. Make sure there is no whitespace:

```html
<a href="index.html"><span style="border: solid;" id="logoText">rapitec</span><span style="border: solid;" id="logoPrefix">.com</span></a>
```

2. Use `display: flex;`:

```css
.flexcontainer { display: flex; }
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="flexcontainer">
  <span style="border: solid;" id="logoText">rapitec</span>
  <span style="border: solid;" id="logoPrefix">.com</span>
</a>
```

3. Set the parent element's `font-size: 0;` and re-set on the children:

```css
.inlineblock-container { font-size: 0; }

.inlineblock-container * { font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<a href="index.html" class="inlineblock-container">
  <span style="border: solid;" id="logoText">rapitec</span>
  <span style="border: solid;" id="logoPrefix">.com</span>
</a>
```

The other issue seems not reproducible in your snippet.

Comment: Nice to see the choice of solutions.